# Get Notification on changing UIBUtton BackgroundImage/Image. OR KVO for this

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

Right now I have implemented custom class for UIButton and setting is Image and BackgroundImage via Async, so I want to get the know about when the image has set onto the button so I can remove the UIIndicator from the UIButton.

Comment: If you're using AsyncTask, you can use the onPostExecute() method

Comment: @Merlevede Thanks but my architecture is not that much flexible here and If I am doing this so time will run out, I have to submit code asap. Please suggest me other way too thanks for you reply.

Comment: Can you share some code?